# Factory reset on mako with broken digitizer and TWRP installed

Tags: factory-reset, twrp, broken-screen

I want to factory reset a mako with a broken screen and digitizer so I can sell it. The device is rooted and there is TWRP recovery and Cyanogenmod installed. As the screen and digitizer are broken I cannot control it via the touchscreen.

Therefore I bought an USB OTG cable, but it does not recognize the mouses and keyboards I plugged in while they work perfectly on another phone. I think USB debugging is disabled as I was able to download all the data by plugging the phone into USB.

Comment: Can you boot it into bootloader mode, and do you have Fastboot available? `fastboot erase userdata && fastboot erase cache` should do then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it with the help of a friend, this package ( http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2564453 ) and couple of ADB sideload commands and flashed the stock rom from here:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/occam-lmy48t-factory-416938f1.tgz